# How to stop thread in java, when it is hanged?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How to stop thread in Java, when it is hanged?
I can't use interrupt(), because I can't check interruption flag within hanged thread.
Also stop() is deprecated, because it's unsafe.

Thanks in advance.

update:
thread hangs on Socket.connect():

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket",
            new Class[] { int.class });
final BluetoothSocket socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, port);
socket.connect();
```

Comment: Define what you mean by `thread hanged`

Comment: @Division_Bell If you are on android, [the javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#connect%28%29) states: *"close() can be used to abort this call from another thread."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to shut a thread down cleanly is to have to stop itself gracefully.

If a Thread is blocked on a resource like a Socket read or write, you can try closing it and it will trigger an IOException. How to unblock a thread depends entirely on why it is blocked.

If you are forcing a thread to stop, you have given up the idea it will be stopped gracefully, in which case `Thread.stop()` or `System.exit()` are your only options.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Actually, the problem is, that Socket.close() hangs also

Comment: Can you try `Socket.shutdownOutput()` first? This will stop it trying to send any unflushed data. `Socket.close()` shouldn't block unless your consumer is far too slow.